# Is it possible to display objects, group of objects as bounding boxes?

Tags: 3d-view

My scene grew complex with several geometry nodes. And it takes seconds beetween consequitive viewport updates even in wireframe mode.

Is it possible to display objects, group of objects as bounding boxes?

It would be extremly beneficial for positioning the camera to have smooth viewport update.

I am using Blender 3.0.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make any object display as a bounding box by setting the *Object Properties* → *Display As* setting to *Bounds*:

[image]

However, this may or may not significantly improve your viewport update times, depending on whether the issue is rendering the scene or calculating the geometry node results in the first place. In the latter case, it may be more useful to simply disable some of the offending Geometry Node modifiers in the viewport using this button in the modifier settings:

[image]

This may be more helpful at speeding up updates than simply rendering the object as a bounding box.

Answer (score 7):

With an Object selected. Go to the Object Properties panel > Viewport Display > Display As and change from Textured to Bounds. You can right click the dropdown box and select Copy to Selected to make the whole selection display as Bounds.

[image]